# How do I generate a type for a nested object that has been flattened?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to take a type with with nested objects like this:

```js
type Numbers = {
  numberOfCategories: number,
  colors: {
    numberOfColors: number
  },
  cars: {
    numberOfCars: number
  }
}
```

And automatically generate a type that is a flattened version which looks like this:

```js
type FlattedNumbers = {
  numberOfCategories: number,
  numberOfColors: number
  numberOfCars: number
}
```

I thought something like this would do the trick, but it's not working as I expected:

```js
type Numbers = {
  numberOfCategories: number,
  colors: {
    numberOfColors: number
  },
  cars: {
    numberOfCars: number
  }
}

type ConvertToObjects =
    & (<K, V:Object> (K, V) => V)
    & (<K, V> (K, V) => { K: V })


type Flattened = { ...$Values<$ObjMapi<Numbers, ConvertToObjects>> };

let test = ({
      numberOfCategories: 2,
      numberOfColors: 5,
      numberOfCars: 10
}: Flattened)
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```js
// 15: type Flattened = { ...$Values<$ObjMapi<Numbers, ConvertToObjects>> };
//                                   ^ number [1] is not an object.
// References:
// 2:   numberOfCategories: number,
//                          ^ [1]
```

My goal is to have an equivalent of the `Flattened` function that works correctly.

I made a starting point to play with here: 
[flow playground](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwEYQE4GcoF4oG8BQUUAdoiqgPIBmAwgIbAQDmA9qgJYToBcJZaAGkJQAxiwA2bHnmFFSyNNRoSpveeWEBfIURF0MvAkTn9KtfdPVot+TfnyhIUZcQBuaYABUWFJACsIEWBMLFkoADIoAAoAHgBpASgANW5fAKCAPmiE5IBKbCyk3LDI2JykrKjy-Kws3Cg43iSoTWKHcGgAMXEGRmIIABNsPCgAOnGAEiS6cTguGIm0gFk6MHYY+AUMRJd3VC8ff0DgjKzNAG57cQhgKEZ0W5woo2MTLaUGZjZOaQAmHVefHetBUBigAFYAa8rGZ6GCAIwABlsvG6vQg-QGuSAA)

Answer (score 0):

This looks to have been fixed in [a recent commit](https://github.com/facebook/flow/commit/5c09b8ac379091351c0add3618b774b3ce099927), which was released as a bug fix in [Flow `v0.111.1`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases/tag/v0.111.1) since you posted this question. Your playground link doesn't show any errors on the latest version, but it still appears when using `v0.111.0`.

Comment: Interesting. While it does appear that the error message went away, it's still not accomplishing the proper type goal. It's not validating that the flattened type is correct. See [new playground](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwEYQE4GcoF4oG8BQUUAdoiqgPIBmAwgIbAQDmA9qgJYToBcJZaAGkJQAxiwA2bHnmFFSyNNRoSpveeWEBfIURF0MvAkTn9KtfdPVot+TfnyhIUZcQBuaYABUWFJACsIEWBMLFkoADIoAAoAHgBpASgANW5fAKCAPmiE5IBKbCyk3LDI2JykrKjy-Kws3Cg43iSoTWKHcGgAMXEGRmIIABNsPCgAOnGAEiS6cTguGIm0gFk6MHYY+AUMRJd3VC8ff0DgjKzNAG57cQhgKEZ0W5woo2MTLaUGZjZOaQAmHVefHetBUBigACJiCxbnQgeRwQDXlYzPQwQBGAAMtl43V6EH6A1yQA).